# Update many document based on a condition MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here's my schema

```
{ _id : Number,
  user1: {
   _id : Number, 
   userDetail : {
    userId : Number,
    userResult : String,
   }
  }, 
  user2 : {
   _id : Number, 
   userDetail : {
    userId : Number,
    userResult : String,
   }
  },
 createdAt : Date, 
 updatedAt : Date
}
```

Sample Doc look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("625ebcabcc03685c273b2363"),
    "user1" : {
        "_id" : "625ebc9fcc03685c273b2207",
        "userDetail" : {
            "userId" : 7,
            "userResult" : "won"
        }
    },
    "user2" : {
        "_id" : "625ebc9fcc03685c273b2208",
        "userDetail" : {
            "userId" : 11,
            "userResult" : "lose"
        }
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-19T13:44:11.781Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-19T13:44:11.781Z")
}
```

Now I have nearly 1000 doc where this user has played. So I need to update the userId of all this users. How I am able to do this. I am getting all the user by

```
db.getCollection('matches').find({$or : [{'user1.userDetails.userId' : 7}, 
    {'user2.userDetails.userId' : 7}
]})
```

By the above query I am getting all the doc where userId 7 has played now I need to update the userId 7 to 10. How could I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$cond`:

```
db.collection.update({
  $or: [{"user1.userDetail.userId": 7}, {"user2.userDetail.userId": 7}]
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "user1.userDetail.userId": {
        $cond: [{$eq: ["$user1.userDetail.userId", 7]}, 10, "$user1.userDetail.userId"]},
      "user2.userDetail.userId": {
        $cond: [{$eq: ["$user2.userDetail.userId", 7]}, 10,
          "$user2.userDetail.userId"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{multi: true})
```

As you cna see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-J6f6FM0c4F)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('matches').updateMany({$or : [{"user1.userDetails.userId" : 7}, 
{"user2.userDetails.userId" : 7}]}, { $set: { "user1.userDetails.userId": 10 })
```

Comment: What this does is make both the userId as 10 instead I need is user1.userDetails.userId to be 10 and user2.userDetails.userId to remain 11 as earlier. Now it's updating both as 10.

Comment: I've edited my answer to adjust for this. I hope that works for you!

Comment: Nope this will only update the user1.userDetails.userId, it will for work for this sample doc but will fail for lets say where user2.userDetails.userId equals to 7. In that case only user1.userDetails.userId will be updated.